# How to add a POST request in an existing collection?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-native-app

I am trying to add POST request to an existing collection, Here by default only get request available. How can i change that?

[image: Add request]

Answer (score 0):

You could either

1. Open a new tab (cntrl + T for Win, Ubuntu), select the new blank tab, choose POST request from the drop to the left of the url. Once you enter all details click on the down arrow next to save (right of the URL). Click on `save as` and name your request, add an optional description and then select the collection you wish to add it to.
2. We have different postman versions so I am unable to see the `Add Request` option in my drop down, but I recon you could click that and follow above steps.

Comment: tried 1st option, configuring post request with no body should return response as 404. when i try to send a request it return response as 200(which i am earlier configure body with data should return 200 ) @Varun Agarwal

Comment: That seems as an issue with configuring the actual request you are making (and maybe the server routers). A 404 will come only if the server returns it on purpose, or the url is invalid. It does not depend on whether the request has a body or not.